# Launch full screen video from script

Tags: python

is there any way to launch full screen in a video from a script? SOmething like:

import webbrowser

webbrowser.open('http://test.com/videos/video-1') # this page has videoplayer with flash interface

is there any code that I use so when it opens that page finds the element to toogle fullscreen on the video?

Thank you